# Returning sub class Instances from a super class method in Kotlin that initially returns an instance of the super class

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have a Quadrilateral class that inherits a method called `translate` from a super class `Polygon`. `Polygon` implements an Interface called `Shape`. The current implementation of `translate` in `Polygon` returns a `Polygo`n instance. However, the `Quadrilateral` class implements additional methods specific to quadrilaterals.

When the `translate` method is called on an instance of `Quadrilateral`, it currently returns a `Polygon`. However, my objective is for it to return an instance of `Quadrilateral` instead of a `Polygon` to further work with the `Quadrilateral`.

In reality, I have a more complex scenario with a many more methods and a deeper inheritance structure (e.g., a `Square` or `Rectangle` class that inherits from `Quadrilateral`). My goal is to implement certain methods only once in a super class, but I want to ensure that calling these methods always returns a new instance of the (sub) class on which the method is called on.

I attempted to achieve this using generics and casting `Polygon` to `Quadrilateral` (see second code block `Sample code with Generics` down below), but encountered the following exception:

```kotlin
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class Polygon cannot be cast to class Quadrilateral (Polygon and Quadrilateral are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at MainKt.main(Main.kt:10)
```

I am uncertain if what I am trying to achieve is even possible, and I am not sure if this is a good idea at all and I may reconsider my design, but I am in general interested if there is a way to achieve this in general. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

### Basic sample code (Not working)

```kotlin
interface Shape {

    fun translate(translation: Double): Shape

}

open class Polygon(open val vertices: List<Pair<Double, Double>>) : Shape {

    override fun translate(translation: Double): Polygon {
        return Polygon(vertices.map { Pair(it.first + translation, it.second + translation) })
    }

}

class Quadrilateral(override val vertices: List<Pair<Double, Double>>) : Polygon(vertices) {

    fun scale(factor: Double): Quadrilateral {
        return Quadrilateral(vertices.map { Pair(it.first * factor, it.second * factor) })
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val a = Pair(0.0, 0.0)
    val b = Pair(0.1, 0.0)
    val c = Pair(1.0, 1.0)
    val d = Pair(0.0, 1.0)

    val rect = Quadrilateral(listOf(a, b, c, d))
    
    println(rect.translate(5.0).scale(5.0))
}
```

### Sample code with Generics

```kotlin
interface Shape<T: Shape<T>> {

    fun translate(translation: Double): T

}

open class Polygon<T : Polygon<T>>(open val vertices: List<Pair<Double, Double>>) : Shape<T> {

    override fun translate(translation: Double): T {
        return Polygon(vertices.map { Pair(it.first + translation, it.second + translation) }) as T
    }

}

class Quadrilateral(override val vertices: List<Pair<Double, Double>>) : Polygon<Quadrilateral>(vertices) {

    fun scale(factor: Double): Quadrilateral {
        return Quadrilateral(vertices.map { Pair(it.first * factor, it.second * factor) })
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val a = Pair(0.0, 0.0)
    val b = Pair(0.1, 0.0)
    val c = Pair(1.0, 1.0)
    val d = Pair(0.0, 1.0)

    val rect = Quadrilateral(listOf(a, b, c, d))
    
    println(rect.translate(5.0).scale(5.0))
}
```

Comment: It seems weird that `Quadrilateral` would take a list of vertices in the constructor. This allows you to create quadrilaterals with 5 or more vertices. Is this intended? And are all `Polygon` subclasses like this?

Comment: While using generics here is possible, it gets very complicated very quickly when you have multiple levels of inheritance. This might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and I suggest rethinking your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your approach of using generics is possible, achievable and, I would say, not uncommon. It will be a judgement call whether the extra complexity is beneficial in the context of your wider project, but I would not consider your generic approach so far to be "too much".

There are a few things I would look to change in your code:

1. Use an intermediate abstract class `PolygonBase` so each inheritor is forced to override the methods it needs to;
2. Add in a generic abstract `createNew` function so each instance can create the right type each time that is needed, avoiding any cast and the associated error; and
3. Work with the underlying vertices so that the common translation functionality can be applied to the vertices, being the key characteristic all `PolygonBase` objects share.
4. As an extra, and as @Sweeper says, you may also wish to restrict the number of vertices in the `Quadilateral` to four. Given that is not the main thrust of your question, I've not made any such adjustment in my sample code.

Putting that together, hopefully you will agree this is a bit cleaner:

```
interface Shape<T: Shape<T>> {
    fun translate(translation: Double): T
}

abstract class PolygonBase<T : PolygonBase<T>> : Shape<T> {
    abstract val vertices: List<Pair<Double, Double>>

    protected abstract fun createNew(newVertices: List<Pair<Double, Double>>): T

    override fun translate(translation: Double): T {
        return createNew(vertices.map { pair -> Pair(pair.first + translation, pair.second + translation) })
    }
}

class PolygonImpl(override val vertices: List<Pair<Double, Double>>) : PolygonBase<PolygonImpl>() {
    override fun createNew(newVertices: List<Pair<Double, Double>>): PolygonImpl {
        return PolygonImpl(newVertices)
    }
}

class Quadrilateral(override val vertices: List<Pair<Double, Double>>) : PolygonBase<Quadrilateral>() {
    override fun createNew(newVertices: List<Pair<Double, Double>>): Quadrilateral {
        return Quadrilateral(newVertices)
    }

    fun scale(factor: Double): Quadrilateral {
        return createNew(vertices.map { Pair(it.first * factor, it.second * factor) })
    }
}
```

See in [Kotlin Playground](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>In the playground I changed `Quadilateral` to a data class so we can easily see what its new vertices are using `println()`.